# Many plants need animals to grow (pollination, worms digging up the soil, etc.); when is it still vegan?

Tags: veganism, agriculture

Many plants need animals to grow, for example, by relying on pollination or on worms digging up the soil.  Usually, animals arrive naturally to perform those roles, but in some circumstances, people may choose to "help nature" and introduce pollinators, worms, or other animals to aid the crops.  Is there a particular characteristic to determine when the aid of animals in food production is compatible with a vegan diet, and when it is not?

Comment: Can you think of a way this wouldn't just be opinion based?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Perhaps there exists some form of consensus that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Existence of a consensus, or a couple of commonly accepted consensi, or absence of such, would still be hard knowledge...

Comment: [Are animal pollinated foods vegan friendly?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/1660/89)