# Do vegans consume crops pollinated by captive bee labor?

Tags: is-it-vegan, bees

Bees are used as slave labor to pollinate a huge number of crops. How do we justify the exploitation of honey bees to produce food? Avocados, almonds, and blueberries are just a few examples of crops dependent on prison bee labor.

Comment: Certainly up for debate and has been debated elsewhere (https://www.veganlifemag.com/vegan-myths-avocados-arent-vegan/). It seems to come down to your definition of veganism and acknowledgement that avoiding 100% animal exploitation is near impossible in modern capitalist society.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are animal pollinated foods vegan friendly?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/1660/1236)

Comment: Linked question by Nic and Alexander contains very good answers that would also answer yours. You should go take a look.

Comment: bee are not exploited, pollinating plants is something they naturally do.